# StandardOutput.ReadToEnd Hangs Indefinitely

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

First, I've tried several solutions including the ones listed here. [ProcessStartInfo hanging on "WaitForExit"? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why) and
[StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160187/standardoutput-readtoend-hangs)

None of them are working for me and all of them timeout or hang. Do you see anything obvious in my code that I'm doing wrong? Basically, I am trying to run a shell script via C#. The script runs fine, and takes a while, when you run it manually. (Like one minute) In my code it is HANGING on ReadToEnd. Here's the code...

```
        public psResult RunScript(string scriptToExecute, string scriptArgument)
    {
        var logEnabled = true;

        scriptToExecute = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["s-path"] + scriptToExecute;

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(scriptToExecute))
            return new psResult
            { HasErrors = true, ErrorMessage = $"{scriptToExecute} is not found!" };

        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exe"],
                Arguments = $"{scriptToExecute} {scriptArgument}"
            }
        };

        string logCapture = "";

        try
        {
            process.Start();

            logCapture = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new psResult
            { HasErrors = true, ErrorMessage = $"{e.InnerException}", RawResult = logCapture };
        }

        return new psResult
        { HasErrors = false, ErrorMessage = $"{scriptToExecute}.", RawResult = logCapture };
    }
```

Comment: What is the script being executed? Does that produce any output?

Comment: this is sometimes expected - look at async option - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566166/how-to-asynchronously-read-the-standard-output-stream-and-standard-error-stream

Comment: @Jawad it's a powershell script. Does some remote-junk and sends output to the screen.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I tried that also and it hung on the Peek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a script permission issue for my machine. Once I changed it to ByPass it worked. So, it wasn't the code!